# Algorithm that finds unique numbers that equal N(or an inputed number)

Tags: math, logic

language agnostic question but I wanted to know if anyone can provide guidance logically on how to create a set that through adding or subtracting could generate any number between 1 and N.

Comment: You mean like 2016 = 2000 + 10 + 6? It doesn't seem very hard without some additional constraints. On the other hand, if you constrain the numbers to be chosen from a fixed finite set then you have the subset-sum problem, which is well-known to be NP-complete. Do you have a question in mind which is neither trivial nor infeasible?

Comment: Not given a set, I simply must use any number from 1 to N through which any operations of addition or subtraction would produce a minimal set. In hindsight i probably should have lead with that

Comment: A minimal set that equals N

Comment: N = N. This is a set with 1-element, hence is a minimal set. I think that there is something that you aren't telling us. Constraints matter. Please specify.

Comment: Further information, I'm currently attacking this using the powers of 2. Which tends to leave me with one number that is too big in the set, I can't think logically of how one would take said number and shrink it to make the set equal N

Comment: Let me try once more; For a natural number N,/find a set of natural numbers in a way that if you  were only to use subtraction and summeration , you could generate any Natural number between 1 and N, by using each number of the set once.

Comment: Please use the edit link under your question to add any further details.

Comment: Exactly, but logically I don't have the approach to that. Should I loop through 2^(k-2) sum those and then alter 2^(k-1) so that once the entire set is summed it'll equal N?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An idea.

If we used only summation, then the set consisting of powers of 2 less or equal than N would be such a minimal set. With subtraction, the powers of 3 seems to be an idea good enough for start. I suspect it may be minimal but don't have a proof.

My reasoning is the following. Suppose we have k numbers in the set. Then there are at most 3^k possible results we can get with summation and subtraction. (Note that those results contain negative integers. In fact, such a set of results is symmetric with respect to 0. And, usually, we'll get fewer than 3^k different results - some of them will simply repeat).

**An example of "optimal" choice:**

Let's take the first number equal to 1. Then the possible results are: -1, 0, 1. Next, take 3 - then we'll get all integers between -4 and 4. (Choice of number 2, instead of 3, is clearly inefficient.) Then, to obtain the next contiguous (and non-overlapping) sequence of integers we should take 9. And so on, until number N is reached.

We could use other numbers instead of powers of 3. In such a case, we should take care of gaps that will results in consecutive steps. And I doubt it would produce a set with fewer elements. (I may be wrong, though.)

Answer (score 0):

1. Sort all numbers.
2. Remove duplicates that are next to each other (is current equal to previous?)
3. Add / Subtract the remains.